# Migrate Enable Reports checkbox of a custom object in XML file

Tags: custom-object, metadata-api, package.xml

How can I migrate Enable Reports checkbox of a custom object in package xml file?

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the object metadata that's pulled down when you extract the `CustomObject` entity with the Metadata API. `enableReports` is a top-level key under `<CustomObject>`:

```
<enableReports>true</enableReports>
```

Your `package.xml` must contain an entry along the lines of

```
<types>
    <members>My_Object__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

in order to extract the relevant custom object, but you don't need to do anything additional to include the `enableReports` flag.

Comment: Can you please let me know the exact lines I need to put. It's still failing Sir at my end.

Comment: If you have a specific error, please edit it into your question. As my answer states, you need to include a `CustomObject` entry in your `package.xml`, and you will receive the `enableReports` field automatically.